# How to extract usernames from text in python?

Tags: python

So I have a message such as "Hey @richard01 what time are we meeting @freddy023?" and I need a function to get it to extract the usernames which are always marked by beginning with an @ symbol.

```
def get_username(message, position):
```

So, for example, the following code would output "freddy023"

```
get_username("Hey @richard01 what time are we meeting @freddy023?", 2)
```

Comment: Without regex: `usernames = [x for x in mystring.split() if x.startswith("@")]`

Comment: Why would it output "FredBloggs"? I don't see that anywhere in your sample message.

Comment: From where `FreddBloggs` come?

Comment: So your positions are 1-indexed? Bah..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
import re

test_string = "Hey @richard01 what time are we meeting @freddy023?"

usernames = re.findall("\B@\w+", test_string)

print(usernames)
# Prints: ['@richard01', '@freddy023']
```

Here the regex expression matches the `@` symbol followed by 1 or more word characters (including numbers). The `\B` makes sure the `@` doesn't appear halfway through a word (like in an email)

I highly recommend having a play around with regex to fully understand how this works, Regex101 is brilliant for this. You can see this regular expression in action here: https://regex101.com/r/BOwY5z/1

Comment: thank you very much for the help ill have a look at the link now